# serializing a JSON data packet in a jQuery Ajax POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a data structure like socket

```
var s = {
    "a": "foo",
    "b": 5,
    "c": {"d": "a long string"},
    "e": {
        "f": {
            "g": {
                "h": [1, 0, -2.1, 1.43]
            }
        },
        "i": {
            "j": {
                "k": [-3.2, 3.003, 0, 0]
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I want to store the "a", "b", "c", and "e" keys of variable `s` in a database table so I can reconstruct them back again. I am sending `s` via a jQuery Ajax POST. The values would be inserted and stored as just plain text (except for "b" which is always a number).

```
ajax: {
    url: uri,
    type: "POST",
    data: s,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, status) { .. }
}
```

Here is the problem I am encountering. In Firebug I can see my post parameters… they are really messed up. Seems like the data have been serialized at the level of each element (kinda like a deep serialization) while I was hoping for something like

```
e={"f":{"g":{"h":[1,0,-2.1,1.43]}},"i":{"j":{"k":[-3.2,3.003,0,0]}}}
```

**Update**: Instead, I am getting the following (I have unescaped the string below so it is more readable)

```
a=foo&b=5&c[d]=a long string&e[f][g][h][]=1&e[f][g][h][]=0&e[f][g][h][]=-2.1&e[f][g][h][]=1.43
```

Perhaps I am doing this the wrong way, so feel free to guide me to a better way.

Answer (score 11):

Use `JSON.stringify` method to serialize the data object into string and post it. On the server side just store this as is in your DB. Try this

```
ajax: {
    url: uri,
    type: "POST",
    data: { data: JSON.stringify(s) },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, status) { .. }
}
```

Almost all the modern browsers support JSON natively. For browsers which do not have it natively you can include the required js from http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js

Comment: I'm fairly certain you are going to double encode that data object, since you are calling stringify on s

Comment: If the data value is a string, `jQuery` just does URI encoding to make it safe enough to transfer over HTTP. I don't think so it will encode the string.

Comment: I have added a little bit more explanation... see the update in the OP. JSON.stringify is not really getting me what I want. Again, it is possible there is a better way to accomplish what I want... so feel free to suggest.

Comment: @punkish - Make use of JSON.stringify it will give you a serialize string which is easy to post. If you give the object as it is to jQuery it will create key/value pair for each property at the first level inside it which is what you are seeing in the firebug.

Comment: thank you all... the following did the trick `var str = ""; for (var i in s) {str += i + "=" + (typeof(s[i]) == "object" ? JSON.stringify(s[i]) : S[i]) + "&";}`

Comment: @ShankarSangoli - +1 Saved me alot of headache=)